# changing a group of pixel values at one time MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, pixel

I've found borders of shadow regions in my image, and I can plot these borders on top of the image, but I would like to create a binary image where only the pixel values of these borders are equal to 1. For some reason, when I try to use the location array as indices, it isn't keeping the row values isolated. Instead, it's replacing pixels in an entire block (each x value with all the y values). However, plotting with the same indices gives me the correct shape. For example,

```
>> m=20;
>> location = [5 6;5 7;5 8;5 9;5 10; 5 11;5 12; 5 13; 5 14;5 15;5 5;6 5; 7 5;8 5;9 5;10 5;11 5; 12 5;13 5;14 5;15 5]

location =

     5     6
     5     7
     5     8
     5     9
     5    10
     5    11
     5    12
     5    13
     5    14
     5    15
     5     5
     6     5
     7     5
     8     5
     9     5
    10     5
    11     5
    12     5
    13     5
    14     5
    15     5

>> blank = zeros(m);
>> blank(matrix(:,1),matrix(:,2))=1;
>> figure
>> imagesc(blank)
>> colormap gray
>> hold on
>> plot(matrix(:,2), matrix(:,1), 'g', 'Linewidth', 3)
>> axis image
```

This gives me this:

Well this is my first post...so it wont let me post images but hopefully you understand what I mean. Please help. This has been a thorn in my side for what I am trying to accomplish, and I've just been trying to avoid using it this way.

Answer (score 2):

you should use `sub2ind` \ `ind2sub`  to accomplish that. For example in your case:

```
linearInd = sub2ind([m m], location(:,1),  location(:,2));
blank = zeros(m);
blank(linearInd)=1;
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation for those functions, it seems like they would apply to a situation where I'm going back and forth between indices for a matrix reshaped into a vector and indices for the actual matrix. These are the correct indices though. Each row of my locations array is a pixel (or is supposed to be).

Comment: wow I am sorry I doubted...thank you so much! -just had to change "size(m)" to the actual [m,m] in ur snippet

Comment: @natan - the suggestion to use `sub2ind` is good, but since `m=20`, `size(m) == [1 1]`. As OP pointed out, that breaks your example. I could edit the answer for you but it's better if you do it.